# logrotate: log does not need rotating

Tags: logging, logrotate

logrotate is not rotating my logs

To verify that the logfile is not empty:

```
# ls -laFh /var/log/cisco-meraki.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 2.8G Sep  5 13:23 /var/log/cisco-meraki.log
```

Configuration (/etc/logrotate.d/zzzzz_default):

```
"/var/log/cisco-meraki.log" {
    daily
    rotate 10
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create
}
```

Global config (logrotate.conf):

```
daily
rotate 10
create
include /etc/logrotate.d
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

Trying a manual run:

```
# logrotate --verbose -d zzzzz_default
reading config file zzzzz_default

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: "/var/log/cisco-meraki.log"  after 1 days (10 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/cisco-meraki.log
  log does not need rotating
```

To verify that the problem is not "allready rotated" I checked:

```
# cat /var/lib/logrotate/status|grep cisco
"/var/log/cisco-ace.log" 2016-1-19-16:0:0
"/var/log/cisco-pix.log" 2016-1-19-16:0:0
"/var/log/cisco-acs.log" 2016-1-19-16:0:0
"/var/log/cisco-asa.log" 2016-1-19-16:0:0
"/var/log/cisco-router.log" 2016-9-6-0:1:1
"/var/log/cisco-ips.log" 2016-1-19-16:0:0
```

..but no cisco-meraki.log

Answer (score 4):

From logrotate man page:

```
      -d, --debug
           Turns on debug mode and implies -v.  In debug mode, no
           changes will be made to the logs or to the logrotate
           state file.
```

I was hit with exactly the same issue !

N.

Answer (score 4):

see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96947

Lets say you created your zzzzz_default file today. logrotate will create an entry, **as if it rotated the logs today** in /var/lib/logrotate/status.

When you run `logrotate --verbose -d zzzzz_default` **today**
logrotate checks the last time it rotated logs reading /var/lib/logrotate/status. It will find that entry it created before so it will say `log does not need rotating`

If you run `logrotate --verbose -d zzzzz_default` **tomorrow**
logrotate checks the last time it rotated logs reading /var/lib/logrotate/status. It will **not** find that entry so it will rotate the log files.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and finally found that it was a file permission problem, the configuration file must be set to root, and then use su in the configuration file.

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/logrotate.d/xxx

/var/log/xxx.log {
    su ec2-user ec2-user
    daily
    rotate 10
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 644 ec2-user ec2-user
}
```

if `/etc/logrotate.d/xxx` owner is ec2-user:ec2-user, execute
`sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/xxx` nothing happened.